# Expandable and collapsable tableview with custom cells in iOS

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, customization

please help to make tableview with custom cells, which expands and collapses. All the models which I see are not suitable for me, so I like this model http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/expandable-collapsable-accordio-uitableview/ but implementation is not clear for me and I don't understand how to create custom cells in this model. I need cells with textfields and divided into sections. As I understand I can't create it in IB, so I need "parent" tableview and "child" tableview which expands when I choose "parent" cell. Maybe this is difficult model for me as beginner, and whether are any other models?

Here is my scheme:

[image]

Comment: Try: https://github.com/jonasman/JNExpandableTableView

Answer (score 1):

I have made a sample project for expandable/collapsable tableview. Check it out at

https://github.com/singhson/Expandable-Collapsable-TableView

I Hope it helps you.